# Is there any way for this script to work in texstudio?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to replace using Regular expression in SCRIPT. This code works in texstudio.

```
%SCRIPT
text = app.clipboard
text = text.replace(/{([^}])}{([^}])}{not}/g, "\1\2{not}")
cursor.insertText(text)
```

I expect the output of {match1}{matchb}{not}{anotb} to be match1matchb{not}{anotb}, but the actual output is {not}{anotb}.This code works in texstudio. Great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex to *not* include the braces `{}`, and use the callback argument of `replace` instead:

```js
const str = "{match1}{matchb}{not}{anotb}";

const res = str.replace(/{(.*?)}{(.*?)}{not}/g, (_, m1, m2) => `${m1}${m2}{not}`);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I tried it in texstudio, however it doesn't work. Maybe I do not fully understand how it works. Great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, this expression might return the desired output, not sure though:

```
({[^}]*not[^}]*})|{|}
```

#### Replace with `$1`

```js
const regex = /({[^}]*not[^}]*})|{|}/g;
const str = `{match1}{matchb}{not}{anotb}
and anything elese {match1}{matchb}{and another not field}{ and another anotb}`;
const subst = `$1`;
console.log(str.replace(regex, subst));
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/DCfB6H/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/DCfB6H/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---